# restricting instantiating a class to a certain scope

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

There is a class I am writing, which I want to restrict the users of that class to use it only within classes of type XXX. How can I accomplish this (friends) functionality in PHP?
Talking to the users is not a viable option :-)

Example:

```
class ActionLog{
 ....
 ....
 ....
}

abstract class Controller{ ...}

class BabaController extends Controller{
    public function SuperAction(){
        $X = new ActionLog();; OK!!!
    }
}

class SomeOtherBabaWhichIsNotAController extends SomthingElse{
    public function super_nice_function(){
        $X = new ActionLog();//WILL CRASHHHH!!!!!!!!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should be asking yourself _why_ this is necessary. PHP doesn't have any sort of namespace-level protection of classes as some other languages do. You could examine a backtrace, but that's highly impractical

Comment: write in your documentation what's the appropriate use, and if users still decide to use it the way it's not intended, and it breaks in the future, well, it's not your fault :)

Comment: This is necessary to restrict developer to use the right classes in the right place. I need to restrict the usage of this class to the action, never in an underlying class/object/function call. Not so similar from the concept of Interfaces (why would u restrict there?)

Comment: @Marko D :-) I am not doing open source. It will be my fault, sadly, I do not live in a perfect world/company, I do not always get the best of developers and I do not have any choice...

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka the preferred method of enforcement is to keep a large stick near your desk that you can use to 'correct' the behaviour of the developer using the class improperly.

Comment: @Sammitch Is NERF also good for that? I have prettu large arsenal at my disposal

Comment: Why would you want to mimic one of the most horrid flaws of c++?

Comment: @teresko more like the assembly concept of dotnet. I need to enforce my developers to use this class only in specific locations. I am no psychologist, so I rather solve it in the code vs. threatening/fighting/firing people

Comment: Your whole architecture is broken (assuming the code example is equivalent of the real code). But instead of fixing it, you want to add more bad practices to your code to hide said flaws. A logger should be a decorator, not a hardcoded dependency.

Comment: @tereško if it is a decorator, how do u prevent developers to decorate with it what ever they want? Easy to say something is broken, harder to fix, my observation. Besides, when u be experienced enough u will know u can not make assumptions about real system architecture from a simple code snipet that is targeted ONLY for the purpose of showing what I try to achieve.

Comment: `class SomeLogger{ public function __construct( Controller $controller ) {...}  public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {...} }` This way the mystical logger can only be used with something from `Controller` inheritance chain

Comment: Anything you have tried?